# Tarea de PHP POO

Tags: php, poo

Soy nuevo en POO, estoy trabajando con Php
Logre hacer una tabla con los datos del usuario que quiero mostrar, el inconveniente es; estoy mostrando los datos por foreach las tablas nombre,apellido,edad,estatus etc.

En la casilla de estatus debe aparecer un mensaje de "Activo" si tiene MENOS de 60 años y "Jubilado" si esa persona tiene mas de 60 años

Asi es como se ve:
Imagen: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVmLB.png

Si podrían ayudarme se los agradeciera mucho.

Mi codigo:
-index.php

```html
<?php
    require_once "conexion-poo.php";
    require_once "metodosCrud.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>CRUD</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
    <hr>
    <center><h3>Lista de Usuarios</h3></center>
    <hr/>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedula</td>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>Apellido</td>
            <td>Edad</td>
            <td>Sexo</td>
            <td>Cargo</td>
            <td>Correo</td>
            <td>Estatus</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
<?php
    $obj= new metodos();
    $sql="SELECT cedula,nombre,apellido,edad,sexo,cargo,correo from empleado";
    $datos=$obj->mostrarDatos($sql);
    foreach ($datos as $key ) { 
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key['cedula']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $key['nombre']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $key['apellido']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $key['edad']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $key['sexo']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $key['cargo']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $key['correo']; ?></td>
        <td>  </td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
    </table>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

-conexion-poo.php

```
<?php
class conectar{
    private $servidor="localhost";
    private $usuario="root";
    private $bd="tarea";
    private $password="";

    public function conexion(){
        $conexion=mysqli_connect($this->servidor,
                                $this->usuario,
                                $this->password,
                                $this->bd);
        return $conexion;
    }
} ?>
```

-metodoCrud.php

```
<?php 
class metodos{
    public function mostrarDatos($sql){
        $c= new conectar();
        $conexion=$c->conexion();
        $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
        return mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: Cuál es el problema? Qué error tienes? Por favor haz el [tour] y lee [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo debes agregar una validación en el campo `status` en la que si el valor de `$key['edad']` es menor a `60` se imprima el valor `Activo` sino que se imprima `Jubilado`, en este caso para que sea sencilla utilice una condicional ternaria para colocarla en una sola línea.

**index.php**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedula</td>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>Apellido</td>
            <td>Edad</td>
            <td>Sexo</td>
            <td>Cargo</td>
            <td>Correo</td>
            <td>Estatus</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $obj= new metodos();
    $sql="SELECT cedula,nombre,apellido,edad,sexo,cargo,correo from empleado";
    $datos=$obj->mostrarDatos($sql);
    foreach ($datos as $key ) { 
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $key['cedula']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key['nombre']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key['apellido']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key['edad']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key['sexo']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key['cargo']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key['correo']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo ($key['edad']<60) ? 'Activo' : 'Jubilado'; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvio

Comment: De nada @user319091